# Name Matching using Double Metaphone on BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, fuzzy-comparison, metaphone

I have a Levenshtein UDF loaded in BigQuery for comparing name strings, and would like to consider other algorithms such as Double Metaphone. I'm not sure if/how to load the DM algorithm in BQ and haven't found much literature about it.

Would anyone know if it's possible to load and use Double Metaphone on BigQuery?